# flutter - firebase message click, move paticle screen event

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want when i click Firebase FCM message, move another screen.
Regardless of the background or foreground, I want you to move to a specific screen when you press the notification on all screens.
But I don't know where to put the event or how to put it.
here is my firebase code.
main.dart and firebase_message.dart

main.dart

```
StreamController<String> streamController = StreamController.broadcast();

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
}


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  String? firebasetoken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(); 
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
  print(firebasetoken);
  prefs.setString('firebasetoken', firebasetoken??"");
    runApp(ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 690),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MyApp();
        }));
  }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyApp({
    super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => ThemeProvider()
        ),
      ],
        builder: (context, _) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            initialBinding: BindingsBuilder.put(() => NotificationController(),
                permanent: true
            ),
            builder: (context, child) {
              return MediaQuery(
                  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(),
                  child: child!)
              ;
            },
            home: const Login_check(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

and firebase_messaging.dart

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'main.dart';
class NotificationController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  @override
  void onInit() async{
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    _getToken();
    _onMessage();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void _getToken() async{
    String? token= await messaging.getToken();
    try{
      print(token);
    } catch(e) {}
  }

  final AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.max,
  );
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void _onMessage() async{
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(
            android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'), iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings()),
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      print('foreground.');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      if (message.notification != null) { 
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification!.body}');
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print("$message");
    });
  }
}
```